# Draw.io - Is possible to have descriptions for AWS shapes?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I am surprised that there are AWS shapes available however there are no descriptions of what the shape represent. This make it hard to use them. Am I missing something here?

Comment: No, we just haven't gotten round to putting them in. We'll them for the next release.

Answer (score 1):

They are now enabled in todays (2.1.1.2) release.